# Load array from .byte char

Tags: assembly, arm

I have an array stored like this
I was wondering how can i load this into an array?
Thanks
            .global map
    map:

```
@; map 0:
    .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: That is an array.  Just put a label in front of it if you don't have one already.

Comment: I dont understand what are you saying, what im asking is i have more maps, like map 0, map 2 etc... and i want to load from byte for example 90 to 120

Comment: You mean copy?  Load means memory -> register, like `ldr r0, [r1]`